# Does AS3 have a method similar to PHP's strtr()?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, oop, flash, flashdevelop

I need to replace some characters in a string.
For example:

```
var str:String = 'Hello World!';
```

And I need to change all characters in this string using some table of comparison that is an array. In PHP I would use the `strtr()` method for this purpose. But I couldn't find its analog in AS3.

So, please help! How can I do this in AS3. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use replace function.

If you want to change `e` (only first occurence)

```
var str:String = "Hello world!";
str = str.replace('e', 'x');
```

Result will be:

```
Hxllo world!
```

If you want to change all occurences (for example you ewant to change all `o`)

```
var str:String = "Hello world!";
var pattern:RegExp = /o/g;
str = str.replace(pattern, 'x');
```

Result will be:

```
Hellx wxrld!
```

If you want to change all occurences case insensitive:

```
var str:String = "Hello world!";
var pattern:RegExp = /h/gi;
str = str.replace(pattern, 'x');
```

Result will be:

```
xello world!
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But is there another ways ? Im asking because i have table of chars to replace and using RegExp in loop for replacing all characters in string by chars from table will cost me a lot of preformance (correct me if im wrong).

Comment: Have a nice day. If my answer accomplishes your question, please accept it ;)

Comment: please read my edited post ) im looking forward to your seductions )

Comment: you must define separated RegExp because your replace is different, letter by letter. If you want to change e with x, a with y and t with g you must apply three times the replace functions. You can create a method to factorize your code, but the way is that in my answer

Comment: I see, I hoped that somewhere lies method that I could use like strstr(string_to_replace, array_of_chars). ))

Comment: A punctualization. The correct PHP function is str_replace not strstr. In PHP  str_replace accepts as parameters two arrays (the first for search, the second for replace), so substritution goes in positional way.

Comment: you are correct, but str_replace sometime do not work correclty, that why I used strtr() for purpose to 'replace' chars.

Comment: This is not correct answer. If I want, for example, to do php strtr for "Hello World" to change o to e, and e to o, I would use strtr("Hello World","eo","oe") and I'll get "Holle Werld" which is correct. With your idea, after first replacement e to o, and then o to e, I'll get "Helle Werld"... think about it.